# Showing Associative Array in ListView through Adopter with custom layout item

Tags: listview, arraylist, layout, listitem, adaptor

I am trying to get data from php mysql and show it in my application. I've got the array(Assoc) with two attributes, name and link.

[image]

I have my custom list item designed.

[image]

I want to get the names from the array and put it in every item individually, and show the items in listview, further I want to use the onClick of every item.

[image]

Comment: Hi there, please look at this guide [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  don't post code (or data structures) as images but as text and format it accordingly. Additionally I guess android would be an important tag if that's what you code in.

Comment: how can i edit my question now?

Comment: maybe you don't have the right yet (otherwise you see and edit below your quesation). if so, delete this question and open a new one

Comment: it'll need some time period to ask another, as i 've reached the limit for now

Comment: if you may please answer the question, besides the community rules advice.